# Lanelet2: ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python38.so.1.71.0: undefined symbol: _Py_tracemalloc_config

Tags: boost, boost-python

I am trying to setup lanelet2 package from their git repo. When i try to run the tutorial package on my system running Ubuntu 20.04LTS, i am getting the above error. I tried the same on a python shell and running the command ' import lanelet2', it still throws the same error.

Comment: The changelog for Python 3.9 says that symbol was removed.  What version are you using?

Comment: It's Python 3.8.5

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue was resolved by one of my colleague. It was mainly caused due to libboost version mismatch from anaconda in my setup. Had to uninstall all libboost packages along with anaconda at first. Then installed libboost again. This resolved the error.